# getResourcePath() for folders in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, filesystem

I have a plugin that has an folder inside of it's `resources`. I need to iterate through those files.

To get the path, I tried `craft()->resources->getResourcePath('folder-name')`, but it seems to only succeed if the *file* exists, not a folder.

I want the folder so I can use `IOHelper::getFolderContents($folder)`.

Do I just need to build the path myself (`$folder = craft()->path->getPluginsPath() . 'myplugin/resources/svg/';`), or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ResourcesService getResourcePath](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ResourcesService#getResourcePath-detail) method will only work for files.

The [PathService getResourcesPath](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PathService#getResourcesPath-detail) method will get you the resources path, after which you can append your folder name.

```
$folder = craft()->path->getResourcesPath() . 'svg/';
```